error: no member named 'AccessorSignature' in namespace 'v8'
I'm using

Node - v20.12.2

node-sass- 9.0.0

macOS


when I'm trying to install latest node-sass library this error was thrown
../../nan/nan_callbacks.h:55:23: error: no member named 'AccessorSignature' in namespace 'v8'
typedef v8::Local<v8::AccessorSignature> Sig;
                  ~~~~^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/chamara/Documents/hotel manager/hotel-manager/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.3.0
gyp ERR! command \"/Users/chamara/.nvm/versions/node/v20.12.2/bin/node\" \"/Users/chamara/Documents/hotel manager/hotel-manager/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp\" \"rebuild\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/chamara/Documents/hotel manager/hotel-manager/node_modules/snappy

